# How to Transfer files from Azure to AWS using C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, migration, azure-storage, file-transfer

I have about 200 GB of files in Microsoft Azure. I want to Transfer it to AWS S3.

Is it possible to Transfer all files from Azure to AWS without downloading each file on local machine?

Comment: hello DownVoter? do u have a habbit to downvote without giving any explaination on wats wrong in post?
atleast you should comment if any thing wrong in the post? I am new bee to Azure and AWS..And if u DONT KNOW the answer just LEAVE IT!

Answer (score 1):

This code sample may help you with the file transfer, but you cannot avoid the download of the files to the machine executing the code:

```
using System;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace Sample
{
    class UploadFileFromAzureToS3
    {
        static string existingBucketName = "[Bucket name]";
        static string keyName = "[Your object key]";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1));

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[Storage Account Name];AccountKey=[Storage Account Primary Key]");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("[Your container]");

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("[File Name]");

            using (var fileToUpload = new MemoryStream())
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileToUpload);
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileToUpload, existingBucketName, keyName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you just need to transfer the files once, you may use the blob storage backup service from RedGate: https://cloudservices.red-gate.com/Home/Features#storageBackup (you have a 10 day trial).

Comment: cant we do this using C#?